# Ioctl returns 140733193388544 for sector size

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

I am learning some stuff about disks and now trying to get the size of a sector and number of sectors on a  disk.

```
int main(void){

extern int errno;
//variables needed
size_t disk_size;
size_t sector_size;

//Open /dev/sdc
int fd_disk = open("/dev/sdc", (O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK));

if(ioctl(fd_disk, BLKGETSIZE, &disk_size) < 0){
    printf("Error: ioctl");
    return 0;
}


if (ioctl(fd_disk, BLKSSZGET, &sector_size) < 0){
    printf("Error: ioctl");
    if(errno == EBADF){
        printf("fd is not a valid file descriptor");
        return 0;
    }else if(errno == EFAULT){
        printf("argp references an inaccessible memory area");
        return 0;
    }

}

printf("Number of blocks: %zu\nSector Size: %zu\n", disk_size, sector_size);

return 0;
}
```

The first call returns the correct value, the number of sectors on a disk but the second one returns 140733193388544 which is far from 512 default one.

fdisk util says sector size is 512 which they acquire via ioctl call in the same manner.

Comment: 140733193388544 == 0x7fff00000200L, are you sure `size_t` is the size expected for BLKSSZGET?

Comment: `man 2 ioctl_list` says: pointers to unsigned log and int for the pass-by-reference parameters.

Comment: @user786653 it says it should be unsigned long,w ell it actually says "The third
       argument is an untyped pointer to memory." but many examples on github say ti should be unsigned long

Comment: @user786653 ioctl_list has nothing about BLKSSZGET so i assumed it would be ul

Comment: @user786653 just tried with int and it works. no idea why it is not documented

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19756066/786653) - even though it's a bit old - seems to suggest it expects an `int`.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/sd.4.html  has "BLKGETSIZE
              Returns the device size in sectors.  The ioctl(2) parameter
              should be a pointer to a long."